# Why doesn't Bash `(())` work inside `[[]]`?

Tags: linux, bash

```
[[ " stop start status " =~ " $2 " && (($#<3)) ]] || { echo "Usage $0 file_name command"; exit 1;}
```

I frequently use the above solution to check the input range of my Bash script.

Now I realise that the extended arithmetic expression `(())` looks like it is suppressed inside the double bracket `[[]]`.

To illustrate the problem:

```
a=start; n=1; [[ " stop start status " =~ " $a " && (($n<3)) ]] && echo ok || echo bad
ok
a=start; n=5; [[ " stop start status " =~ " $a " && (($n<3)) ]] && echo ok || echo bad
bad

# But:
a=start; n=100; [[ " stop start status " =~ " $a " && (($n<3)) ]] && echo ok || echo bad
ok
```

The above result is false because n not less than 3 if they are treated as numbers.
This is the correct solution:

```
a=start; n=100; [[ " stop start status " =~ " $a " ]] && (($n<3)) && echo ok || echo bad
bad
a=start; n=1; [[ " stop start status " =~ " $a " ]] && (($n<3)) && echo ok || echo bad
ok
```

Comment: Short answer: That's not an arithmetic command; it's just a set of nested, redundant parentheses for grouping.

Comment: Also, you don't need to specify `$` in arithmetic expressions, so `((n<3))` suffices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The GNU bash man page for `[[..]]` explains that the operator runs a conditional expression and

> Return a status of `0` or `1` depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression `expression`. Expressions are composed of the primaries described below in [Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

But the arithmetic operator is *not* part of the supported conditional expressions (*primaries*) inside `[[..]]` which means the expression is forced to run as a string comparison, i.e.

```
(( $n < 3))
```

is **not run in arithmetic context** but just as plain lexicographic (string) comparison as

```
[[ 100 < 3 ]]
```

which will always result true, because the ASCII values for `1`, `0`, `0` appear before `3`

But inside `[[..]]` arithmetic operations are supported if you use `-lt`, `-gt`

> `arg1 OP arg2`
>
> OP is one of `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, or `-ge`. These arithmetic binary operators return true if `arg1` is equal to, not equal to, less than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or equal to `arg2`, respectively.

So had you written your expression as

```
a=start; n=100; [[ " stop start status " =~ " $a " && $n -lt 3 ]] && echo ok || echo bad
bad
```

it would have worked as expected.

Or even if you had forced the arithmetic expression usage by prefixing `$` before `((..))` and written it as below (note that bash does not have documented behavior for `$((..))` inside `[[..]]`). The likely expected behavior is the arithmetic expression is expanded before the `[[..]]` is evaluated and the resultant output is evaluated in a string context as `[[ 0 ]]` which means a non-empty string.

```
a=start; n=5; [[ " stop start status " =~ " $a " && $(( $n < 3 )) ]] && echo ok || echo bad
```

The result would still look bad, because the arithmetic expression inside `[[..]]` decomposes into an unary string not empty comparison expression as

```
$(( 5 < 3 ))
0
[[ -n 0 ]]
```

The result of the arithmetic evaluation `0` (false) is taken as a non-zero entity by the test operator and asserts true on the right-side of `&&`. The same would apply for the other case also e.g. say `n=1`

```
$(( 1 < 3 ))
1
[[ -n 1 ]]
```

So long story short, use the right operands for arithmetic operation inside `[[..]]`.

Comment: I assume that it's undefined behavior instead of necessarily a string comparison, because `[[` operates on tokens whereas `((` doesn't have a defined expansion, but passes results via its return code? For example `n=100;[[ (($n<3)) ]] returns 0 whereas `n=100;[[ ((n<3)) ]]` returns 1.

Comment: @rubystallion: bash does not have an undefined behavior per.se. If you look the debug mode output, you can clearly see the evaluation is done as a string comparison. Your second case fails because `[[` does a string comparison `[[ n < 3 ]]` is false (rc: 1) because ASCII `n` is higher than `3`

Comment: Right, i see it now. The two parentheses are simply interpreted as nested single parentheses according to the `( expression )` rule of `[[`, thanks!

Comment: @Inian, thanks for the detailed and inspiring answer,
Now I understand that the bash iterpreter treats everything as an expression inside the `[[]]`.
so `a=1;[[ ((a=2)) ]]; echo $a  # a=1 remain` and with `$` command substitution
`a=1;[[ $((a=2)) ]]; echo $a  # a=2` of course, but I would need the return code of `$(())` instead of the result of `$(())`.
The problem was caused by my faulty expression that could work well for certain data (e.g.: single digits)
when the string and numeric sorting was the same.
I wonder if there are a lot of such "misunderstandings" in bash?

Answer (score 7):

`((` is a "keyword" that introduces the arithmetic statement. Inside `[[`, however, you can't use other statements. You *can* use parentheses to group expressions though, so that's what `(( ... ))` is: a redundant "double group". The following are all equivalent, due to the precedences of `<` and `&&`:

- `[[ " stop start status " =~ " $2 " && (($#<3)) ]]`
- `[[ " stop start status " =~ " $2 " && ($#<3) ]]`
- `[[ " stop start status " =~ " $2 " && $#<3 ]]`

If you want integer comparison, use `-lt` instead of `<`, but you also don't need to fit everything inside `[[ ... ]]`. You can use a conditional statement and an arithmetic statement together in a command list.

```
{ [[ " stop start status " =~ " $2 " ]] && (($#<3)) ; } || { echo "Usage $0 file_name command"; exit 1;}
```

In this case, `... && ... || ...` will work the way you expect, though in general that is not the case. Prefer an `if` statement instead.

```
if [[ " stop start status " =~ " $2 " ]] && (($#<3)); then
  echo "Usage $0 file_name command"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: As I see I can use other statements inside [[ e.g.:  `[[ $(date) =~ $(echo May) ]]&& echo This is true for a few more days`   I think my question is: `[[ (( 1 < 3 )) && (( 100 < 3 )) && ! (( 5 < 3 )) ]] && echo arithmetic expression is suppressed`

Comment: Those aren't statements; they are command substitutions, which *contain* other commands. To evaluate a command substitution, you execute the code inside and use what it writes to standard output as the value of the substitution. `((...))` is an entirely different construct. Again, `[[ (( 1 < 3 )) && ... ]]` isn't using an arithmetic command; it's just using parentheses to group the expressions inside the `[[ ... ]]`.